# Format specifier for printing contents of "stat" buffer

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, stat

I used the **stat()** function on linux to retrieve details about a file.
One of the details is time of last access stored in variable "**st_atime**"
But what is the format specifier to display this detail.My program keeps throwing errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
  struct stat buf;
  stat("reversi.py",&buf);
  printf("The size  is...%d\n",buf.st_atime);
  return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__time_t’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The size  is...%d\n",buf.st_atime);
```

What is the correct format specifier for this kind of data.
Also there are several more details returned by the function.Is there a place where i could find all the correct format specifiers for these details.?
Thank You.

Comment: Use e.g. [`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) to format a time into a string. Or one of the [related date/time functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it gets tedious if i have to convert all the details.Any shorcut?

Comment: That's how it works, there's no standard `printf` format to print times.

Comment: There is another detail about the number of blocks allocated.it's of type **__blkcnt_t** . How do i print this detail.I am unable to find anything on the internet.

Comment: Search for it's definition (it's typically a `typedef` alias defined in some header file, `<sys/types.h>` maybe). Or just try different [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format codes, like `"%ld"`, `"%llu"`, `"%hd"`, etc.

Comment: Why is `printf("%s", asctime(buf.st_atime))` so tedious? It's one function call away. Note that because of the internal static buffer used by `asctime` you must print the conversions of each of the three timestamp fields before you convert the next. Remembering the pointer from each conversion and then printing all three won't work. Alternatively, you could copy each string to a local buffer before printing. Or, there are better versions of `asctime`, such as the MSVC `asctime_s` which takes a buffer argument.

Comment: **__STD_TYPE __BLKCNT_T_TYPE __blkcnt_t;**
This is what i found in **types.h** . There is no typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ctime()**, **gmtime()** and **localtime()** functions all takes **time_t** data type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct stat buf;
    stat("1.c",&buf);
    printf("Last Access was :  %s\n",ctime(&buf.st_atime));
    return 0;
}
```

this will print

```
Last Access was :  Tue Apr 28 10:09:15 2015
```